# How can I sort items by the array of numbers in elasticsearch?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I am using elasticsearch version 7.11 and I want to sort items by the array of numbers: lucky_numbers.number_list

A have a lot of elements like below and arrays have a dynamic length, example:

```
....
 _source {
     "game.name": "Twisted Game",
     "lucky_numbers": [
     {
      "number_list": "9"
     },
     {
      "number_list": "11"
     },
     {
      "number_list": "102"
     }
     ]
 },
 ....
  _source {
     "game.name": "Number Roulette",
     "lucky_numbers": [
     {
      "number_list": "10"
     },
     {
      "number_list": "11"
     },
     {
      "number_list": "99"
     },
     {
      "number_list": "102"
     }
     ]
 },
 ....
  _source {
     "game.name": "Numeric Odyssey",
     "lucky_numbers": [
     {
      "number_list": "9"
     },
     {
      "number_list": "12"
     },
     {
      "number_list": "100"
     }
     ]
 }
```

If I use a sorting script and concatenate these sorted numbers into a string, I get the order:

"10,11,99,102"
"9,11,102",
"9,12,100"

But I want the correct numerical order:
"9,11,102",
"9,12,100"
"10,11,99,102"

How can I do this? I know that sort have e.g. option mode:min for arrays, but I want to consider all numbers in array, not just the lowest value. Maybe I can write my own comparator?

Answer (score 0):

In your script, when concatenating the numbers together, you need to zero-pad them on the left so all numbers have three positions. That way you'll always sort them in the right order.

```
009,011,102
009,012,100
010,011,099,102
```

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch [script sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-sort-context.html) can help. Here is an example for you.

```
POST test_lucky/_bulk
{ "index": {}}
{ "game.name": "Twisted Game", "lucky_numbers": [{ "number_list": "9" }, { "number_list": "11" }, { "number_list": "102" }] }
{ "index": {}}
{ "game.name": "Number Roulette", "lucky_numbers": [{ "number_list": "10" }, { "number_list": "11" }, { "number_list": "99" }, { "number_list": "102" }] }
{ "index": {}}
{ "game.name": "Numeric Odyssey", "lucky_numbers": [{ "number_list": "9" }, { "number_list": "12" }, { "number_list": "100" }] }

GET test_lucky/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
      "sort" : {
        "_script" : {
            "script" : "String s = ''; for(int i = 0; i < params._source.lucky_numbers.length; ++i) {s += params._source.lucky_numbers[i] + ','}  s",
            "type" : "string",
            "order" : "asc"
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 3,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test_lucky",
        "_id": "Kv1xQogBVSbrfAXEoHUk",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "game.name": "Number Roulette",
          "lucky_numbers": [
            {
              "number_list": "10"
            },
            {
              "number_list": "11"
            },
            {
              "number_list": "99"
            },
            {
              "number_list": "102"
            }
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          "{number_list=10},{number_list=11},{number_list=99},{number_list=102},"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_lucky",
        "_id": "Kf1xQogBVSbrfAXEoHUk",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "game.name": "Twisted Game",
          "lucky_numbers": [
            {
              "number_list": "9"
            },
            {
              "number_list": "11"
            },
            {
              "number_list": "102"
            }
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          "{number_list=9},{number_list=11},{number_list=102},"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_lucky",
        "_id": "K_1xQogBVSbrfAXEoHUk",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "game.name": "Numeric Odyssey",
          "lucky_numbers": [
            {
              "number_list": "9"
            },
            {
              "number_list": "12"
            },
            {
              "number_list": "100"
            }
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          "{number_list=9},{number_list=12},{number_list=100},"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```